# How to get a closed contour of an object?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, contour, canny-operator

I need to segment the images of cans and bottles in order to classify them later by the shape of the area. To do this, I'm trying to find a closed contour of the object. I use the **Canny** algorithm and **closing morphological operation**. As a result of this, I don't always get a **closed** contour to find the mask.
There are three features:

1. It is acceptable if the contour **is not quite accurate**. The main goal is classification into a can and a bottle, which is feasible even with inaccurate contours.
2. The final project should be rewritten in c++, so it is necessary to use the libraries that are available in this language.
3. The segmentation process **should not be too long**. 40-45 seconds are allocated for the entire photo processing cycle. Therefore, no more than 20-25 should be spent on segmentation.

Based on requirements 2 and 3, **OpenCV** is the preferred development tool, but it is not necessary.

**Examples**

- Expected

[image: Closed contour]
** What I get **

- Correct

[image: Source]

[image: Canny]

[image: Closing]

- Incorrect

[image: Canny]

[image: Closing]

**What I've tried**

1. **Сanny with closing** (described above)

```py
canny = cv.Canny(cropped,t1,t2)
kernel_close = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,ksize = (45,45))
closed = cv.morphologyEx(canny,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel_close)
```

2. **Canny with pre-blurring**
   I got the best results with a gaussian kernel size of 30, but the contour is not closed here either.
   [image: Result]

```py
def get_edges(gray,t1k,t2k,ksize = 3):
    Gk = cv.getGaussianKernel(ksize,-1)
    kx,ky =cv.getDerivKernels(1,0,3,normalize=True)
    blured = cv.sepFilter2D(gray,cv.CV_64F,Gk,Gk)
    dx = cv.sepFilter2D(blured,-1,kx,ky)
    dy = cv.sepFilter2D(blured,-1,ky,kx)
    max_val = max(dx.max(),dy.max())
    t1 = max_val*t1k
    t2 = max_val*t2k
    edges = cv.Canny(np.int16(dx),np.int16(dy),t1,t2)
    return blured,edges
    
    t1=0.2
    t2 = t1*2
    ksize = 30
    blured,edges = get_edges(gray,t1,t2,ksize)
```

3. **Active contour models algorithm by scikit-image**
   Gives a closed contour, which is what I need. However, the final project should be written in c++. I have not found a suitable implementation of this method in c++.

[image: Result]
*(red is the initial snake, blue is the result)*.

**Update.**
Bottles can vary greatly in color and transparency. Here are examples

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Comment: you can apply [YOLO](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) before filtering and binarizing.

Comment: Does this question with answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17538366/18667225 ?

Comment: @Markus, it uses the active contour method. To date, the authors of OpenCv have removed the implementation of this method from the library.

Comment: Ah, ok. Another possibility could be working with [alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) algorithm (e.g. CGAL lib).

Comment: Canny detects regions where there is a strong edge. It does not find closed contours. Do not use it if you need closed contours. If you have a fixed environment (fixed camera, fixed background, fixed illumination), take a picture without the bottle, then put the bottle in and take another picture. The difference is the bottle. This will work well even for mostly transparant bottles, as the color of the pixels will change because of the glass or plastic in the way.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I'll ask for a photo of the background, thanks for the idea. However, I have already tried to apply this method with another batch of photos, without a strictly fixed camera. In this case, nothing good came out. I hope it will work with a fixed camera.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I think I can try to remove the background using morphological operations.

Comment: If the everything is fixed, this works, and it's the simplest, fastest and best way to solve the problem. If things change, such as when the camera is hand-held, or you illuminate the scene using a window, this will not work.